# R Notebook: TOC is not kept on the left when knitting to html

Tags: r, knitr, rnotebook

I have the following R notebook:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "by me"
date: 'last updated: Jan 23, 2022'
output:
  html_notebook:
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    number_sections: yes
    highlight: haddock
---

# First headline

## Second headline

```{r}
1:5
```
````

When I click on "preview", it creates an html document that keeps the TOC on the left side (as expected). When I click on "knit to html", it puts the TOC in the main body of the document. It's still a TOC, but at the wrong place. It also doesn't collapse the individual headlines anymore and instead shows the full ToC.

How can I keep the ToC on the left and keep the headlines collapsed per default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you knit to HTML, in reality knitr is using the definitions for `html_document`, so if you add the appropriate YAML header, it should work.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "by me"
date: 'last updated: Jan 23, 2022'
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    df_print: paged
    number_sections: yes
    highlight: haddock
  html_notebook:
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    number_sections: yes
    highlight: haddock
---

# First headline

## Second headline

```{r}
1:5
```
````

[image: Example of "knit to HTMLE"]

Comment: Additionally, you can check https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html, for a more in-depth explanation of the notebook format

Comment: Thanks, this did the job.